# implementing merge inversions finder

Tags: python, merge

```
import sys

def get_number_of_inversions(a, b, left, right):
    number_of_inversions = 0
    if right - left <= 1:
        return number_of_inversions
    ave = (left + right) // 2
    number_of_inversions += get_number_of_inversions(a, b, left, ave)
    number_of_inversions += get_number_of_inversions(a, b, ave, right)
    #write your code here
    return number_of_inversions

if __name__ == '__main__':
    input = sys.stdin.read()
    n, *a = list(map(int, input.split()))
    b = n * [0]
    print(get_number_of_inversions(a, b, 0, len(a)))
```

this code should be implemented only in 'write your code here' area

and what i was trying to do whole day:

```
i=left
j=ave
k=left
temp_num=0
while i<ave and j<right:
    if a[i]<=a[j]:
        b[k]=a[i]
        i+=1
    else:
        b[k]=a[j]
        j+=1
        temp_num += (ave-i)
    k+=1

number_of_inversions+=temp_num
```

and second try not so smart :

```
left=a[:ave]
right=a[ave:]

result = list()
i,j = 0,0
inv_count = 0
while i < len(left) and j < len(right):
    if left[i] < right[j]:
        result.append(left[i])
        i += 1
    elif right[j] < left[i]:
        result.append(right[j])
        j += 1
        inv_count += (len(left)-i)
result += left[i:]
result += right[j:]

number_of_inversions +=inv_count
```

most problematic for me is:

program begin running with right index one bigger than actually is
first make recursive calls 
program don't give back sub arrays instead returns inversions number only

please give me some suggestions how to implement that code

Answer (score 0):

I am not really sure what you are trying to do
But the problem might be here `right - left <= 1` .
I believe it should be `right <= left`

Comment: i can only change code in place where #write your code here comment is